# Declare array of struct literal

Tags: go

How do I declare an array of struct literal?

Go:

```
type Ping struct {
    Content []aContent
}

type aContent struct {
    Type        string
    Id          string
    Created_at  int64
}

func main() {
    f := Ping{Content: []aContent{Type: "Hello", Id: "asdf"}}
    fmt.Println(f)
}
```

The code can be found here: http://play.golang.org/p/-SyRw6dDUm

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You just need another pair of braces.

```
[]aContent{{Type: "Hello", Id: "asdf"}, {Type: "World", Id: "ghij"}}
           ^                                                      ^
         here                                                    and here
```

That's one pair for the array, one for each struct in the array..

Edit: Fixed the brackets

Answer (score 0):

You actually forgot to pass an array (as @nos showed) an passing a single object by mistake. I have braked down the scopes to show it more easily ([the code is available here](https://go.dev/play/p/1e1ybVQqO2J)):

```
func main() {
    f := Ping {
        Content: []aContent { //  Start declaring the array of `aContent`s

            { //  Specify a single `aContent`
                Type: "Hello",
                Id:   "object1",
            },

            { //  Specify another single `aContent` if needed
                Type: "World",
                Id:   "object2",
            },
            
        }, //  End declaring the array of `aContent`s
    }
    fmt.Println(f)
}
```

---

#### Use better naming

I highly recommend to use better naming to reduce ambiguity. For example by using `Contents` (with the plural `s`) you can quickly determine that is an Array. And you can name the struct as `Content` instead of `aContent`. (no need for extra `a` to show that is a single object)

So the refactored version would be [like this](https://go.dev/play/p/FWw2ewBdL0c)